# Can we get the iPhone crash logs thro app?

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

Can we get the crsah logs thro app ?

Will NSFileManager/NSData help us to accesss .crash files from iphone ?

Is there any way to get it, except the well-known iTunes sync method...??

Thanks in advance.

Gopi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Thanks Shaggy Frog.

To get the crash reports , I thought that I need to communicate with an user, and help them find the logs, they can email to me.

But later( after posting this question) I found that, we can get logs from iTunes Connect.
Apple allows us to see the some crash logs ,where developers can manage applications they have on the App Store, check their sales, and get promotional codes for their apps.

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/05/02/itunes-connect-now-lets-developers-see-crash-reports/

Thank you all!!

Have a great day!!

Answer (score 4):

There are also other ways: my company just released a service for just that purpose: http://apphance.com . You add a simple framework project to your app, integrate it (takes about 5 minutes) and you can see all the logs and crashes from your application in a web panel, where the logs, crashes, memory exceptions etc. are all available. It's automagically available from a web panel, without telling the tester whet should be sent where. The tester can also report issues directly from the application including screenshots.

The service is currently in closed beta stage and you can request beta access to it.

Answer (score 1):

No, apps can not access their crash logs programatically. Apps can't access the file system outside of their sandbox (i.e. your application's directory).